# Dynamic Attribute with google Apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, dynamic, attributes

I make an API call to extract data and include them in a table on a sheet sheet: the table contains columns (the construction of the columns is done in the script also I enter the name of each header), to fill the lines with the data corresponding to each header, I use the `URL Fetchapp` method.

Each header corresponds to an attribute in the API, it is these attributes that make it possible to fill in the lines, my API is used to retrieve food products, each product is known in the API through a unique serial number, c is the one that I enter as a parameter and when I execute my script the line is filled.

My problem is with attributes, when these are present on the platform for the product and the data is filled in the script works, when the attribute is present in the platform for the product but the data is not filled in, I use that in the line of code corresponding to the attribute to neutralize the null:
for example :
`product.annualEnergyConsumptionNumber[0] != null? product.annualEnergyConsumptionNumber[0].data:' ',`

But when the attribute is not present at all on the platform it blocks the whole script, knowing that I retrieve data from several products, some fields are filled in for some and not for others, do you have any idea? which would make my attributes more dynamic?

```
product.annualEnergyConsumptionNumber[0] != null? product.annualEnergyConsumptionNumber[0].data:' ',
```

Comment: Tried `??` null coalescing operator?

Answer (score 0):

When you do `product.annualEnergyConsumptionNumber[0] != null ? product.annualEnergyConsumptionNumber[0].data : ' '`

You're saying "if the first element of the annualEnergyConsumptionNumber is not null, then use its value otherwise use ' '". This assumes two things:

1. the property `annualEnergyConsumptionNumber` exists on the object `product`
2. its type makes possible the use of the `[]` operator (like strings, arrays...)

If, in some cases, `annualEnergyConsumptionNumber` is not returned at all (not present on the `product` object), then you should have one more test in your code

```
if (Array.isArray(product.annualEnergyConsumptionNumber)) {
  let myValue = product.annualEnergyConsumptionNumber[0] != null ? product.annualEnergyConsumptionNumber[0].data : ' '
} else {
  // deal with it
}
```